# Могу ли я создать несколько взаимосвязанных записей в sequelize за один запрос

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

Есть 2 таблицы:

```
class User extends Model{}
Test1.init({
    id:{type: DataTypes.INTEGER , autoIncrement: true, primaryKey: true, allowNull: false, unique:true},
    name:{type: DataTypes.STRING},
    job:{type: DataTypes.STRING}
},
    {
        sequelize,
        modelName: 'User',
        tableName: 'User',
        timestamps:false})


class Post extends Model{}
Test2.init({
        id:{type: DataTypes.INTEGER , autoIncrement: true, primaryKey: true, allowNull: false, unique:true},
        user_id:{type: DataTypes.INTEGER, references:{model:'User', key:'id'}},
        text:{type: DataTypes.STRING},
    },
    {
        sequelize,
        modelName: 'Post',
        tableName: 'Post',
        timestamps:false})
```

Связь обозначена через :

```
User.hasMany(Post, {foreignKey:'user_id'})
Post.belongsTo(User, {foreignKey:'id'})
```

Моя цель - добавить юзера и пост со взаимосвязью user_id / id

То есть, я хочу, чтобы получилась следующая запись:

```
User:
id | name | job

0  | Ivan | builder

Post:
id | user_id | text
0  |   0     | some text...
```

Могу ли я сделать это средствами Sequelize?
Попробовал несколько вариантов, но все безуспешны

Answer (score 0):

Да, можно.

```
        await userModel.create([{
            name: user.name,
            post: user.post
            ...
        }], {
            include: [{
                model: postModel,
            }]
        })
```

Мы создаем одновременно User и Post. Переменная user содержит имя пользователя и пост, при этом пост содержит переменную text